# Why doesn't my system use hardware rendering?

Tags: drivers, ati, xorg

Almost everything which is remotely using my GPU lags horribly, so I decided to dive into the system to check.

```
chloridecull@SonicRainboom:~$ glxinfo | grep renderer
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.2, 128 bits)
```

A quick excerpt from the [RadeonDriver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver#Testing_The_Driver) page on the wiki tells me:

> To see your OpenGL information, you can run the commands below. Make sure your OpenGL renderer string does not say "software rasterizer" or "llvmpipe" because that would mean you have no 3D hardware acceleration:

The output from lshw is below, showing that I have a 7970 using the radeon driver which should happily accept whatever is thrown at it.

```
chloridecull@SonicRainboom:~$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Tahiti XT [Radeon HD 7970]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:46 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fbc80000-fbcbffff ioport:ee00(size=256) memory:fbc00000-fbc1ffff
```

dpkg reports that the xserver-xorg-video-radeon is at version 1:7.1.0-0ubuntu2. I had fglrx installed before this, but I purged it by following the guide on the [VideoDriverDetection](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection#Problem%3a_Need_to_purge_-fglrx) page.

How do I enable 3D hardware processing?

Comment: +1 I'm getting the same result from a VM despite having hardware rendering passed on from the guest.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting the stick from another usb port and/or another computer to test if the usb port or stick is bad.

Load the boot image on another usb stick and see if that works.

Comment: This is already installed from the Minimal (netinst) iso.

Comment: This means that (almost) all packages are installed from apt-get, including the X server and drivers.